# How I can specify the metastore of Hive in Apache Spark program using java?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark, hive

I have written a java code for running SparkSQL on Hive. I am trying to give the path of my hive metastore to the program but is it not working at all.
See the program:

```
String warehouseLocation = "file:${system:user.dir}/spark-warehouse";

SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();
try
{
      spark.sql("select count(*) from health1 ").show();
}
catch (Exception AnalysisException)
{
    System.out.print("\nTable is not found\n");
}
```

My metastore_db is at location: `/home/aims/hadoop/hadoop/hive/var/lib/metastore_db`
I want that any operation that I am trying to do using SparkSQL should be reflected on the Hadoop with HIVE. For that purpose I need to have the metastore_db connected to my Maven program.
How I can do that?  Is there a way I can give my `hive-site.xml` path in the program using config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the Hive Metastore Server like below.

```
hive --service metastore &
```

Now you can connect to hive using Spark by setting the config `hive.metastore.uris`

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate();

spark.sql("select count(*) from health1").show();
```

Comment: May i know from where you reached to conclusion `"thrift://localhost:9083"`? I do not get this.

Comment: When you run the metastore server you will get details in console. Something like "INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Started the new metaserver on port [9083]"

Comment: Thank you.. you solved a lot of big problem for me... :)

Comment: Can you please post separate question and paste full log message.

Answer (score 0):

Place your core-site.xml and hive-site.xml on the resources folder and Spark will automatically look for those files and initialize metastore for Hive. Also set logging level to INFO to see information regarding Hive metastore.

Comment: how I can do it using eclipse? I am actually using the IDE. please let n=me know